Flink job produces bad characters with a queueLimit > 1
I'm trying to fix an old flink job, and running into some issues.  If setQueueLimit is > 1, i will randomly get messages where the key becomes part of the message, along with some bad characters, and the key becomes to "a" (I set the default key to 0)
����
1721403548{"id":1}{"id":2}{"id":3}k�6��!�ı^�`��

If only 1 json message is submitted through, no problems, only when its more than one.
I have checked my datastream by printing out in intellij, and so far I can't see any reason for this problem.  I have even gone so far as making my messages be near empty json and I filter out anything that is not alphanumeric or needed for json.
I think it has to be how my sink is made.
  def createSink(stream: Option[String], region: Option[String]): FlinkKinesisProducer[String] = {
    val outputProperties = new Properties
    outputProperties setProperty(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_REGION, region.get)
    outputProperties setProperty("Region", region.get)
    outputProperties.put("RecordTtl", s"${Int.MaxValue}")

    outputProperties.put("ThreadPoolSize", "5")
    outputProperties.put("MaxConnections", "5")
    val sink = new FlinkKinesisProducer[String](new SimpleStringSchema, outputProperties)
    sink setDefaultStream stream.get
    sink setDefaultPartition "0"
    sink setCustomPartitioner new KinesisPartitioner[String]() {
      override def getPartitionId(element: String): String = {
        val epoch = LocalDateTime.now.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
        epoch.toString
  }
}
sink setQueueLimit 500
sink

}
Any ideas?  I don't think I want to set my queue limit to 1, but i need clean data to be sent!  Thanks
